# How to subclass UIApplication?

Tags: iphone

The iPhone Reference Libary - UIApplication says I can subclass UIApplication, but if I try this I will get an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There can only be one UIApplication instance.'
```

This reminds me of the Highlander "There can be only one,. :-)

Do I have to pass other argurments to UIApplicationMain? Or did I missread  somthing in the libary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213279/objective-c-project-with-swift-uiapplication-subclass-error-class-not-loaded

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you pass the name of your subclass to UIApplicationMain? Let's assume you have

```
@interface MyUIApp : UIApplication 
...
```

then in main() you should do:

```
NSString* appClass = @"MyUIApp";
NSString* delegateClass = nil;
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, appClass, delegateClass);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the same way as suggested in answer... but i'm still getting the same error... Anything else i need to do...?

Comment: How can i retrive this "MyUIApp" class's object ?

Comment: MyUIApp* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

Comment: @TeemuKurppa  What is for swift 4 or later ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam the same but in Swift syntax. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1622933-uiapplicationmain

Answer (score 13):

In your app's info.plist, make sure you change the `NSPrincipalClass` key to the name of your subclass (In Swift prefix it with `AppName.`). This'll make Cocoa instantiate the correct class when the applications loads - you shouldn't have to do anything other than that to get your subclass working.

Comment: There is no NSPrincipalClass key in my info.plist. Should i add it?

Comment: Yes - there are many, many keys that could be in your Info.plist - they aren't all included by default.

Comment: This seems Mac OS X only, not for iPhone OS: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW1

Comment: Works on tvOS (and I am certain also on iOS) and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Can confirm it works on iOS

Comment: Edited this to add note about prefixing with module name in Swift

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one and accepted answer is o.k., but to make it clear...

Let's say you have:

`UIApplication` subclassed as `MyApplication`

`UIApplicationDelegate` subclassed as `MyAppDelegate`

Then your main.m would look like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "MyApplication.h"
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc,
                                 argv,
                                 NSStringFromClass([MyApplication class]),
                                 NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));                
    }
}
```

In case you did not subclass `UIApplication` or `UIApplicationDelegate` you simply pass `nil` to the `UIApplicationMain` as the respective parameter.

Comment: What would be the swift implementation ?

Answer (score -5):

There can only be one UIApplication instance in an application, you should not initialize the one new application object, use the static method of the UIApplication:+ (UIApplication *)sharedApplication.