# how to retrieve link from text view?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

how to retrieve a link from text view. When user click an link , i need to capture that link.
Any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Just implement [`-application:handleOpenURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW15) in your app delegate. Return NO to avoid opening the URL.</del>

Just [subclass UIApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399202/how-to-subclass-uiapplication) and override [its `-openURL:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:), e.g.

```
-(BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)theURL {
   if (shouldOpenURL(theURL))
     return [super openURL:theURL];
   else
     return NO;
}
```

Comment: Wrong answer. The application:handleOpenURL is called, when external party tries to open some URL using your application. This question was about catching url opening within same application --> use UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect clicks in regular `UITextView`. If you want that functionality, use `UIWebView` instead, and implement `UIWebViewDelegate`, so you can intercept clicks by implementing this method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```