# how to detect idle user in iphone-sdk

Tags: iphone, uiapplication, python-idle

In my Application I want to call Logout Function if user is idle for certain amount of time how to accomplish

this answer doesn't work for me 
[iPhone: Detecting user inactivity/idle time since last screen touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch)
 if i subclass my app delegate class from UIApplication and implement

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

It gives me error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There can only be one UIApplication instance.'
```

I can't find the other instance of UIApplication in my application

so far i have done

instead of

```
@interface IdleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
```

I have changed it to

```
@interface IdleAppDelegate : UIApplication<UIApplicationDelegate> {
```

and in the main instead of

```
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

I've changed it to

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"IdleAppDelegate", @"IdleAppDelegate");
```

Is there anything remaining to do?

I'm getting the above error... am I missing something...?

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you didn't subclass it right?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399202/how-to-subclass-uiapplication

Comment: Thanks for you comment... But i have implemented this way only 
I have inherited my appDelegate class from UIApplication  and in inside main I have written int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, appClass, delegateClass); also where appClass is the name of my appDelegate Class

Comment: I have edited the question and put the code of how i subclass it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application class is also an application delegate class - that's bad. `UIApplicationMain()` will create an instance of your custom application subclass, which will then try to an instance of its delegate - which is also an instance of your custom application subclass. You should separate these concerns - yes your custom app subclass needs to subclass `UIApplication`, but your app delegate should be a separate class that subclasses `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks Graham... But My Application doesn't have any Custom app class...What should i do...?

Comment: @mihirpmehta it does, according to the code in your question. Is that up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

{
    NSLog(@"Application not Active");
    // FETCH THE CURRENT TIME 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but... It will getting called when application itself become inactive... like when incoming call OR receiving SMS etc... Not fulfilling my requirement