# With iOS 5 SDK how can I use the Custom UIApplication in my iOS App?

Tags: ios5, uiapplication

I wanted to customize UIApplication. So I have a subclassed UIApplication. My Application do not have a MainWindow.nib file. So how can I assign my Custom UIApplication to play the role of UIApplication?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399202/how-to-subclass-uiapplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer provided by Link pointed by petert solved my problem.

In the Main.m file I was able to assign the CustomApplication and CustomAppDelegate this way:

```
 int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"CustomApplication", NSStringFromClass([CustomApplicationDelegate class]));
```