# vfr/reader pdf external links open in UIWebView instead of Safari

Tags: ios

How can I detect when a user clicked an external link and safari is going to open.

Instead I would like to catch this event and create a UIWebView inside my application. Is this possible with vfr/reader?

EDIT:

I found out that vfr/reader does this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:target];
```

Is there away to NOT modify vfr/reader and customize the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the [Open Source vfr/reader code](https://github.com/vfr/Reader), right?

Why couldn't you just replace the `openURL:target` call that it uses with a `[yourAppDelegate openURLInMyBuiltInUIWebView: target]` method instead?

Or, since you're saying you don't want to modify the vfr/reader code, perhaps you could subclass `UIApplication` and replace the `openURL:target` call to do what you want.

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399202/how-to-subclass-uiapplication) that might help you do that.