# How know when app open a URL?

Tags: ios, openurl, telprompt

I'm working on an iOS app and looking to see if it is possible to know when a user opens a URL (for example, user press a button and executes code like below)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://1234567890"]]
```

telprompt: show an alert when it's called. But I want a way to detect if user press Ok button or Cancel button. I need execute some code in `-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` depending which button was pressed.  Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass UIApplication and over-ride openURL: 
This will give you control and have you decide what to do. 
Make sure to call super implementation though if you want to open the URL

**EDIT**

Here is an example

[How to subclass UIApplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399202/how-to-subclass-uiapplication)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it sounds interesting. But, I'm not pretty sure how implement that, but will investigate the matter. Do you have some code?

Comment: See the EDIT. I added a link.

Comment: Thanks I'll give a look later, I am currently experimenting with **`<CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>`** seems that here too there are options for my problem.

Comment: Sorry to re-open this subject but I have the same problem that human4 and I'm beginning in iOS development. I don't see how to resolve the problem by sublassing UIApplication. Do you advice to create our own dialog (with call/ cancel buttons) ? If it's this, by calling super implementation, an other dialog will appear ! If it's another kind of implementation, I don't understand what is it. Is there a way to have access to buttons created by the openURL function ? Have you an example to give us ? Thanks you per advance for your help.