# Recognise all touches in interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to be able to recognise ALL touches in an interface, no matter what was touched.

I've tried:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

.. but this just recognises when the user taps on something that doesn't respond to taps (uiimages for instance)

The reason i need this ability is that I want to kick in a slide show if the user doesn't touch the screen for 5 minutes, so I want to reset the timer whenever they touch. It seems wrong to put this reset code in each UI event individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible solutions, but as said @omz - overriding the `sendEvent:` it is the best one.

```
@interface YourWindow : UIWindow {
    NSDate timeOfLastTouch;
}
@end

@implementation YourWindow
 - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
      UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if( touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded ){
         timeOfLastTouch = [NSDate date];
    }
} 



@end
```

Do not forget replace UIWindow with YourWindow.

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass `UIWindow` and override the [`sendEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWindow/sendEvent%3a) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the `UIWindow` and override the `sendEvent:` method like this:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
     // You got a touch, do whatever you like
  };

  [super sendEvent:event];  // Let the window do the propagation of the event
}
```

Comment: @omz Sorry I just saw your answer... I was typing mine at the same time :P

Comment: You mean in the app delegate instead one the standard UIWindow *window? Since I don't want this to trigger in every part of the app (just most) it seems better to do this per ViewController.. is there a way to do that?

Comment: As far as I know it's difficult to implement this into separate UIViewControllers. The reason is that the first responder for any event (including touches) is the `UIApplication`. Then the event is propagated to the UIWindow and then it tries to find the view (a `UIResponder` subclass) to handle the event. So if you want to catch all the touch events I think the best approach is to create a subclass of `UIWindow` (or `UIApplication`)

Comment: subclassing `UIWindow` and then using `NSNotificationCenter` to notify the specific viewController would be a good way to go

Answer (score 1):

you could use a tap gesture

In your interface add the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
```

then in your viewDidLoad add this

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapMethod)];
tapped.delegate=self;
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

then do your timer code in the tapped method

```
-(void)tapped {
 //timer code
}
```

Make sure you UI elements have `setUserInteractionEnabled:YES`

Answer (score 1):

As @Alladinian said in one of the comments, iOS Reference Documentation mentions that subclassing UIApplication is the right application and thus, seems preferred to subclassing UIWindow. cf. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html :

> You might decide to subclass UIApplication to override sendEvent: or
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent: to implement custom event and action
>   dispatching.

Comment: This is the correct answer! For subclassing of application you can also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399202/how-to-subclass-uiapplication