# Objective-C project with Swift UIApplication subclass. Error: class not loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiapplication

I have a project written in Objective-C and I just added a UIApplication subclass using Swift: `RMFApplication.swift` (implementation at end of post). However, I am getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to instantiate the
>   UIApplication subclass instance. No class named **RMFApplication** is
>   loaded.'

- In my info.plist I correctly specified the name under
  NSPrincipalClass, and double checked it.
- I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24021180/220820) and then looked in my own `main.m` which says: `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RMFAppDelegate class]));`.
- The docs for `UIApplicationMain` say that if `nil` is specified as the thrid value then `UIApplication` is assumed, but why then does my error message include my custom class name? I have to assume `nil` means it will read the info.plist value.

**Note:** Subclassing UIApplication worked well with `RMFApplication.h` and
   `RMFApplication.m`. The only thing that changed was the renaming of
   those files and the addition of a `RMFApplication.swift` file, which
   compiles with no warnings:

```
import UIKit

class RMFApplication: UIApplication {

    override func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool
    {
        println(url.description)
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am aware that I can just continue using Objective-C, but I would like to try and migrate to Swift unless the two really don't play well together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe that's because it uses NSStringFromClass or something, so that in Swift RMFApplication is ["mangled" and becomes something like "somePrefix"RMFApplication](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html) (or whatever different from just "RMFApplication").

You could try this:

```
@objc(RMFApplication) class RMFApplication: UIApplication
```

And then NSStringFromClass will return just "RMFApplication".

Comment: Bullseye, thank you :) After googling "@objc" I found this which will hopefully also help someone else: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html