# Objective C: is it possible to intercept all user actions by one class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to intercept all user actions like tap, swipe, enter text, etc. on all windows of my app?

Comment: add an UIView with clear color background and full size of screen as the first view

Comment: Wouldn't it override all underlying elements? Is there an interceptor-style code to do it?

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to subclass `UIApplication` and override `sendEvent`.

Comment: Can I dynamically override sendEvent() at runtime?

Comment: @Artem search for "Objective-C method swizzling"

Comment: Swipe it is not atomic action, it is gesture, that contains many touches. Also with other "actions".  
I think, more clear solution is create custom UIViewControllerClass, who will be listener for all actions and events, what you want. 
For example, if you want be notified about any touches and gestures, you can add UITapGestureRecognizer to the controller's view;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, subclass `UIApplication` and override the instance method `sendEvent:`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/sendEvent:) for the UIApplication class, `-sendEvent:` method:

> **Discussion**
>
> If you require it, you can intercept incoming events by
>   subclassing UIApplication and overriding this method. For every event
>   you intercept, you must dispatch it by calling [super sendEvent:event]
>   after handling the event in your implementation.

So, it would look like this:

**CustomUIApplication.h:**

```
@interface CustomUIApplication:UIApplication
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
@end
```

**CustomUIApplication.m:**

```
@implementation CustomUIApplication

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // ...Do your thing...

    [super sendEvent:event];
}
@end
```

Of course, you need to make sure your subclass is used instead of the default `UIApplication`. [Here is a Stack Overflow answer on how to do it in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1399287/433373), and [here in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24021180/433373).